# NextJS Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (7:0)

Tags: node.js, next.js

```
[ error ] ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 7:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* FONT PATH
|  * -------------------------- */
> @font-face {
|   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
|   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
```

I've installed next-css, my next.config.json is:

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({});
```

Comment: Looks like the parser don't like the "@" which is silly for a CSS parser. Maybe have a look at their issues board : https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22You+may+need+an+appropriate+loader%22

Comment: I tried commenting out the @font-face bit of the file and it couldn't load the code after it. So the loader just doesn't work :(. Not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: I've also tried using css-loader and style-loader using their recommended config and the exact same error came up.

Comment: Are you trying to use fontawesome?  If that's the case, you can look at this page and follow the guide : 

https://gist.github.com/mehmetnyarar/6739ed1b72245f2b8afcea4464636931

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/432:

Installing next-css in conjunction with url-loader, file-loader and css-loader with the next.config.json fixes the problem.

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    })
    return config
  }
})
```

I also had my next.config.json file named .next.config.json :P, so with next.config.json the error should be `ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)` instead.